# Trouble building a custom loss function in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, computer-vision

I have been trying to develop the YOLO cost function which I have shown below. This is the first time I have tried to develop my own cost function in Tensorflow and am unsure if I am approaching it correctly or not. For one, my model uses a number of intermediate steps. I not sure if this complicates the computational graph in some meaningfully destructive way? Or, I am using an abs. value step and am unsure whether it would have some negative effect on my backprop? Any assistance would be helpful in regard to whether I am approaching this problem correctly.

I can answer any questions about my implementation.

Note - Z13 is the prediction, y are the true values. There are 49 cells in my model (7x7) with each cell being represented by a 7x1 vector: [prob of anything in cell, x midpoint, y midpoint, box width, box height, prob dog, prob cat] .Referenced paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.02640.pdf which explains the cost function in depth.

I believe that there is either an issue with my forward prop or my cost function as my model is not learning meaningful representations.

[image: YOLO cost function]

```
def cost_function(Z13,y,coord=5,noobj=0.5):
    """
    Z13: shape (None,7,7,7)
    y: shape (None,7,7,7)
    """

    # Masks are used as classification score for box coords only applies to cell where actual bounding box is
    c_mask_true = y[:,:,:,0:1] > 0 # Mask which determines which cell has bounding box
    c_mask_false = y[:,:,:,0:1] < 1 # Mask for cells w/o bounding boxes

    # Confidence scores
    ci_guess_t = tf.boolean_mask(Z13[:,:,:,0:1],c_mask_true)
    ci_guess_f = tf.boolean_mask(Z13[:,:,:,0:1],c_mask_false)
    ci_act_t = tf.boolean_mask(y[:,:,:,0:1],c_mask_true)
    ci_act_f = tf.boolean_mask(y[:,:,:,0:1],c_mask_false)

    # Bounding box coordinated for ground truth box prediction
    xi_guess = tf.boolean_mask(Z13[:,:,:,1:2],c_mask_true) # Midpoint x position
    xi_act = tf.boolean_mask(y[:,:,:,1:2],c_mask_true)
    yi_guess = tf.boolean_mask(Z13[:,:,:,2:3],c_mask_true) # Midpoint y position
    yi_act = tf.boolean_mask(y[:,:,:,2:3],c_mask_true)
    # Width:
    wi_guess = tf.boolean_mask(Z13[:,:,:,3:4],c_mask_true) # Midpoint width pos.
    wi_guess = tf.minimum(tf.sqrt(tf.abs(wi_guess)),wi_guess) # prevent sqrt(neg) and increase cost for neg prediction
    wi_act = tf.sqrt(tf.boolean_mask(y[:,:,:,3:4],c_mask_true))
    # Height:
    hi_guess = tf.boolean_mask(Z13[:,:,:,4:5],c_mask_true) # Midpoint height pos.
    hi_guess = tf.minimum(tf.sqrt(tf.abs(hi_guess)),hi_guess) # prevent sqrt(neg) and increase cost for neg prediction
    hi_act = tf.sqrt(tf.boolean_mask(y[:,:,:,4:5],c_mask_true))   

    # Predicted classes: 
    class_g_dog = tf.boolean_mask(Z13[:,:,:,5:6],c_mask_true)
    class_t_dog = tf.boolean_mask(y[:,:,:,5:6],c_mask_true)
    class_g_cat = tf.boolean_mask(Z13[:,:,:,6:7],c_mask_true)
    class_t_cat = tf.boolean_mask(y[:,:,:,6:7],c_mask_true)

    # Parts correspond with the cost function equations above
    part1 = coord * tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(xi_act - xi_guess)+tf.square(yi_act - yi_guess))
    part2 = coord * tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(wi_act - wi_guess)+tf.square(hi_act - hi_guess))
    part3 = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(ci_act_t - ci_guess_t))
    part4 = noobj * tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(ci_act_f - ci_guess_f))
    part5 = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(class_t_dog - class_g_dog)+tf.square(class_t_cat - class_g_cat))
    total_cost = part1 + part2 + part3 + part4 + part5

    return total_cost
```